# Partition not getting created in kafka spring boot

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am creating topic dynamically in spring boot on my local machine.But when described the the topic there was only one partition.
Below is the code.

```
    @Bean
        public NewTopic newTopic() {
    
            return new NewTopic("kafkaTopic",20,(short)2);
 //return TopicBuilder.name("kafkaTopic").partitions(15).replicas(2).build();// tried with as well.
        }
```

o/p:-

```
Topic: kafkaTopic   TopicId: ZiypKK48Q0GqcNwsx6323Q PartitionCount: 1   ReplicationFactor: Configs: 
    Topic: kafkaTopic   Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

Looked through net but not able to resolve issue.

Config code

```
@Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactoryString() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();

        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, server);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

@Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, server);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroupId);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "200");
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "550000");
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "55000");
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "25000");

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configProps);
    }
```

Did i miss any configuration or anything to add?

Comment: Configuration looks correct; if you are using Boot, it should automatically configure a `KafkaAdmin` bean; use a debugger in `KafkaAdmin.afterSingletonsInstantiated()` to see what's going wrong.

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks for helping out.Issue of replica factor number mismatch.

Comment: @prateekjangid Replication factor value is more than the number of Brokers which is the potential issue seems like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown by the CLI describe output, you only have one broker. Therefore, you are limited to one replica, rather than 2.